# What is value held in selector of task register? Index or byte-offsets?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, intel, memory-segmentation

I'm studying old linux kernel source(linux-0.11), some macros defined in `sched.h`:

```c
#define FIRST_TSS_ENTRY 4
#define _TSS(n) ((((unsigned long) n)<<4)+(FIRST_TSS_ENTRY<<3))
#define ltr(n) __asm__("ltr %%ax"::"a" (_TSS(n)))
```

It loads byte-offsets into the selector part of task register, but as per Intel 80386 manual, the selector consists of **index**, **TI** and **RPL** parts. It makes me confused.

Comment: Is `n` a byte offset? Can you show more context?

Comment: `n` is a task number. I means that `_TSS()` calculates the byte-offsets of task `n` in **GDT**.@Jester

Comment: Not sure what you are confused about then, it's shifted by 4 to the left so it goes into the index part all right, even scaled by 2?

Comment: I strongly recommend NOT thinking of the selector as a byte offset, because it's not. It's an index value followed by 3 bits for the GDT/LDT flag and RPL, that *happens* to be the same as the byte offset if the lower 3 bits are all 0.